# Remove Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have got a canvas which has rectangles with an `onClick` event.
When i click the first rectangle it shows exactly the data as i want in my div classes but when i click the other rectangle it says undefined. It shows undefined because i don't have it in my Json and i am not planning to add it but i am gonna add other data.

Is it possible to hide the "`Undefined`"

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8oeg5m1m/)

I don't have "`text`" in my jquery but i want to show for example text in rectangle 5 and to do that im giving each json an unique code.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8oeg5m1m/1/

Comment: POST your code in the question, not just a fiddle. Using code blocks to get around the filter is bad. Stackoverflow supports snipplets which is just like a watered down version of jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the value to not to be undefined before you use in in the string you append:

```
var myStr = 'Something'; 
if(typeof mydata[i].LocalTimeZone !== 'undefined'){
    myStr +=  mydata[i].LocalTimeZone;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it with your function

```
var x;
if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
    // these statements execute
} else {
    //do your task
}
```

Comment: @dennisschagt Could you make a fiddle?

Comment: @Script I'm not the answerer, I only edited this answer to fix the code markup. gaurav wrote this answer. Stackoverflow is not meant to make your homework/applications but we can help if you have a specific question. It helps when you make a [minimal, comple, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).